# requests with wincertstore python

Tags: python, request, cert

I want to make a 'request' request, post, to a URL only that request needs to be signed. I can do it, passing the certificate in pfx and his password. But I want to do it by taking and using a certificate that is installed on the computer, on the Windows certmgr. How can I do this?

```
import requests
import base64
import contextlib
import OpenSSL.crypto
import tempfile

class Token():
    def __init__(self, urlAuthenticate, consumer_key, consumer_secret, caminho_certificado_pfx, senha_certificado):
        self.urlAuthenticate = urlAuthenticate
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.caminho_certificado_pfx = caminho_certificado_pfx
        self.senha_certificado = senha_certificado

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def carregarCertificado(self, caminho_certificado, senha_certificado):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem', delete=False) as t_pem:
            f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
            pfx = open(caminho_certificado, 'rb').read()
            p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, senha_certificado)
            f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
            f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
            ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
            if ca is not None:
                for cert in ca:
                    f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
            f_pem.close()
            yield t_pem.name

    def getChave(self):
        chave = self.consumer_key + ':' + self.consumer_secret
        chave_bytes = chave.encode('utf8')
        chave_base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(chave_bytes)
        chave_base64_string = chave_base64_bytes.decode('utf8')
        return(chave_base64_string)

    def getHeaders(self, chave):        
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + chave,
            'role-type': 'TERCEIROS',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
        return headers

    def getDados(self):
        data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
        return data

    def gerarToken(self):
        headers = self.getHeaders(self.getChave())
        data = self.getDados()
        with self.carregarCertificado(self.caminho_certificado_pfx, self.senha_certificado) as cert:
            requisicao = requests.post(url=self.urlAuthenticate, headers=headers, cert=cert, data=data)
            token = requisicao.json()
            return(token)


token = Token('url/authenticate', 'cbaaaa', 'abcccccc', 'cert.pfx', '1234') 
print(token.gerarToken())
```